# Is there a way to minimize the $p$-distance between a point and a line?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry

Let $x = (x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a point and $L(t) = (b_1, ..., b_n) + t(m_1, ..., m_n)$ be a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to find the point on $L$ that is nearest to $x$ with respect to the distance induced by the $p$-norm i.e. where

$$ || y - z ||_p = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{|y_i - z_i|^p}\right)^{1/p}$$

For $p = 2$ this isn't bad. If I let $h(t) = ||x - L(t)||_2^2$ then I just do

$$h(t) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(x_i - b_i - tm_i)}$$

$$\frac{dh}{dt} = 2\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(x_i - b_i - tm_i)(-m_i)}$$

Setting this equal to zero and solving for $t$ gets me

$$t = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{m_i(x_i - b_i)}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{m_i^2}}$$

However, when I try this for general $p$ I need to use absolute values and I don't get a linear equation to solve. Maybe a different approach is better?